# Parsing XML with Python's Minidom

Tags: python, xml, youtube, minidom

I'm having a little trouble parsing a Youtube XML file with Minidom. The contents of the file are found at this [link](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated?max=results=5&time=today). I saved it in a file named "`ytxml.xml`".

The problem I'm running into is that I'm unable to get all the information I need out of this file.

At this point, I'm trying to get the first "`href`" attributes from the  tags (where the "`href`" corresponds to the video file's YouTube link). I have gotten the user instance, video title, username, and descriptions of the videos so far but I can't get those "`href`" links.

Where am going wrong?  I've looked for a similar question but I didn't really find anything that helped.  Here is my code so far:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parse("ytxml.xml")

def getNodeText(node):
    nodelist = node.childNodes
    result = []
    for node in nodelist:
        if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            result.append(node.data)
        return ' '.join(result)


tag_one = doc.getElementsByTagName("entry")
tag_two = doc.getElementsByTagName("media:player")

for tag in tag_one:
    media_title = tag.getAttribute("media:title")
    media_title_data = tag.getElementsByTagName("media:title")[0]
    print getNodeText(media_title_data)
    media_desc = tag.getAttribute("media:description")
    media_desc_data = tag.getElementsByTagName("media:description")[0]
    print getNodeText(media_desc_data)
    author = tag.getAttribute("name")
    author_data = tag.getElementsByTagName("name")[0]
    print getNodeText(author_data)
    user_instance = tag.getAttribute("uri")
    user_instance_data = tag.getElementsByTagName("uri")[0]
    print getNodeText(user_instance_data)


for tag in tag_two:
    media_player_data = tag.getAttribute("href")
    print media_player_data
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The last for loop is just printing out a bunch of blank stuff...

Answer (score 0):

The last for loop returned blank spaces because it was returning NoneTypes.  It turns out the data I needed was located under the `content` tag as `src`. Also... i recommend not using Minidom. BeautifulSoup is much better!